# Pull only highest level contact

Tags: sql, ms-access, criteria

I'm still new to Access so please bear with me...

In our database we have accounts that are a Company and within the Company account there are 1-4 contacts. These contacts are listed as A,B,C, & D. I have a query that pulls the company and lists all the contacts associated with it.

My question is... is there a way to just pull ONLY the highest level contact? For example, IF no A, then B, IF no B, then C, IF no C, then D?

Would this be a criteria in the contact field?

Comment: What is the table structure like? In particular, is it normalised into separate Company and Contact tables, or are the contact details in the Company table? If the former, in what table is the level (A, B, C or D) of an individual contact recorded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get what you want from a `GROUP BY` query.  In this example, `contact_id` is the field which holds the A-D values:

```
SELECT
    y.company_id,
    Min(y.contact_id) AS highest_level_contact
FROM YourTable AS y
GROUP BY y.company_id;
```

That's only an outline to guide you.  But you should start with a new `SELECT` query in the query designer.  Choose the table and the 2 fields. The click the "Totals" icon (which looks like the Greek letter sigma) and choose "Group By" from the dropdown under your `company_id` field and "Min" under the `contact_id` field.